# How to store user specific data in Mysql Database Table?

Tags: android, mysql, database

I have an Android Application that has posts, news, events, polls, etc

Now i want is to let users rate the above things, and 1 user can rate a post only once.

So how will I store the data like which post is rated by which users and how will i store them in a table cell.

I have unique user id that i am getting via Facebook login, and i also have unique post id for every post.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: post_ratings(user_id*,post_id*,rating) where * = component of PRIMARY KEY

Comment: Ya I had figured out my solution. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I am new to Mysql so can you tell if PRIMARY KEY can be applied to Varchar as well?

Comment: You should be able to figure that out for yourself - but I'd just store a tinyint (0 or 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to maintain consistency, you need that information is stored on the server side (on the client side would be easy to break this restriction ) .

In this case, you could create a new table in which the user id and the id of the post are the primary key, in this way you ensure that these pairs are unique.

As you say these fields are varchar, you will get something similar to:

`CREATE TABLE rating_post
  ( 
     userid  VARCHAR(255), 
     postid  VARCHAR(255),
     rating  TINYINT,
     PRIMARY KEY (userid, postid) 
  )`

Comment: Ok i got you. What do you mean by saying that a field is a primary key?

Comment: When a field is a primary key means that the field can not be null and the value has to be unique. In this case what will be unique is the pair userid, postid, that is, it is not allowed to have two rows with the same values for userid and postid (but you can have repeated userid as long as the postid be different and vice versa).

Comment: No problem. Great! :)